# Moving taskbar on mobile phones screws CSS background gradients

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am trying to create a page which currently has a fixed background with a linear gradient, e.g:

```
.content {
  display: grid;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #3e5151, #decba4);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

So on desktop and mobile this fills the viewport, and doesn't change when scrolling due to the `background-attachment: fixed` property. My problem is, that on mobile, most phones have a retractable address bar or similar. On my phone this bar is at the bottom, so when I scroll, this bar disappears, i.e. giving me more height. However, this also means that this gradient background needs to re-render, which it doesn't do until I let go with my finger. The result is a white bar at the bottom, until the background gradient has been re-rendered with the new height viewport. And this doesn't look all that good to be honest.

Is there any way to fix this so that this doesn't happen, or...?

Answer (score 0):

That is a tricky solution to solve as `100vh` changes height upon scroll. Instead, what if you put that on the `body` element like so?

```
body {
  display: grid;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #3e5151, #decba4);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that result in the same thing?

Comment: @DenverDang No, actually. That was my original thought as well, but I made a demo of it and tested on my phone. I experienced the same issue with `.content` that you described, but not with `body`. There may be other issues at play. Does it work for you?